# Serving static file in django on Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-staticfiles

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test_site.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com

#<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
#AssignUserID USERNAME USERNAME
#</IfModule>

DocumentRoot /var/www/test_site.com
<Directory />
Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

#Alias /static/ /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/static/
#<Location "/static/">
#Options -Indexes
#</Location>
Alias /robots.txt /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/static/

<Directory /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/static>
Require all granted
Options -Indexes
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/media>
Require all granted
Options -Indexes
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test_site.com/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess test_site.com python-path=/var/www/test_site.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=test_site.com
WSGIProcessGroup test_site.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my virtual host file on apache i am having problem to server static files my pache version is newest one and os is ubuntu 14.04 server here is my settings file

```
"""
Django settings for testproject project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '20uuf(=u2+a&(!pbij6ka%_-m(l24baz^4+o^c@!#rfczhq=_r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'temp'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

"""DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}"""
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'temp',
        'USER': 'root',
 'PASSWORD': 'pAssw0rd',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/
```

'please some one guide what i did wrong and what thing i am missing here

Comment: what's not working?  Is apache spitting out any errors via the logs?  any access denied errors?  Cannot find the directory?

Comment: no apache is not showing in error regarding this

Comment: if you go to yoursite.com/static and nothing comes up or you get an error page then apache will definitely log it and tell you what happened.  Apache can be finicky about how you define your aliases, i don't have access to my config right now, when I do I will compare with yours.  Everything *looks* okay at first glance.